# Trouble cloning a set of selects dependent on each other

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am trying to create a dynamic table that allows the user to select from around 100 variables. These variables have been split into categories and I have been displaying them in a second `select` that depends on the user selecting a value in the first `select`. I have been searching the web for answers and have come up blank. I realize that the clone() call will duplicate all data and for that reason id's are a poor choice for the rows.

Here is what I currently have for HTML:

```
        <body>
                <table name='myTable' class="dynatable">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th class='idCol' >ID</th>
                            <th>Category</th>
                            <th>Metric</th>
                            <th>Conditional</th>
                            <th><button class="add">Add</button></th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <form name='myForm'>
                            <tr class="first">
                                <td class="id idCol"><input type="text" name="id[]" value="0" /></td>
                                <td><select name='categories' onChange='updatemetrics(this.selectedIndex)' style="width: 260px">
                                    <option selected>--Select Category--</option>
                                    <option value='1'>Customer Experience</option>
                                    <option value='2'>Key Satisfaction Identifiers</option>
                                    <option value='3'>Personnel Costs</option>
<!-- I have cut the rest out for the sake of brevity. -->
                                    </select></td>

<!-- This is the select that populates based on the user's choice. -->
    <td><select style="width: 310px"name='metrics'></select></td>
                            </tr>
                    </form>
                </tbody>
            </table>
             </body>
```

The Javascript that I am working with is as follows.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
            var id = 0;

            // Add button functionality
            $("table.dynatable button.add").click(function() {
                id++;
                var master = $(this).parents("table.dynatable");

            // Get a new row based on the prototype row
                var prot = master.find(".prototype").clone(true);
                prot.attr("class", "")
                prot.find(".id").attr("value", id);

                master.find("tbody").append(prot);
            });

            // Remove button functionality
            $("table.dynatable button.remove").live("click", function() {
                $(this).parents("tr").remove();

            });
        });

        //script for dynamically populating the metrics select
        var metricCategories=document.myForm.categories;
        var metricList=document.myForm.metrics;

        var metrics=new Array()
        metrics[0]=" "                      
        metrics[1]=['Wait time average|waitInLine','Mystery Shopper Scores|mysteryScores']
        metrics[2]=['Referral Rate|ref_rate','Facebook Shares|facebook_shares','Twitter Followers|twit_followers','Customer Complaint Calls|comp_calls']
        metrics[3]=['Pension Payouts|pension_pay', 'Full Time Employees|ftes', 'Part Time Employees|ptes', 'Contractor Costs|contract_costs']

        function updatemetrics(selectedMetricGroup){
            metricList.options.length=0
            if (selectedMetricGroup>0) {
                for (i=0; i<metrics[selectedMetricGroup].length; i++)
                metricList.options[metricList.options.length]=new Option(metrics[selectedMetricGroup][i].split("|")[0], metrics[selectedMetricGroup][i].split("|")[i])
            }
        }
```

Any help would be appreciated. To reiterate the reason I am asking for help, I need to add/ remove rows that hold `select` nodes that interact with each other. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Nathan, if you had _only_ JavaScript, and not tables (just arrays of data), would you be able to solve the issue? I'm asking because I'm trying to figure what you're having trouble with, the actual data manipulation, or the dom being messy

Comment: Ben, I am trying to keep things in a table. The data gets unwieldy quickly and the end view or snapshot will be in a table. Thanks for asking!